# Routing problems (.NET not MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-4.0, routes

I am using routing in my .net website.

I want this url

`http://www.website.com/condos/rent/{state}/{area}`

To go to `http://www.website.com/condos.aspx` and then pick up the state and area.

This works fine:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("CondosForRentInArea", "condos/rent/{state}/
{area}", "~/condos.aspx");
```

But I am having some problems with the Javascript. Because I can't write:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("StateAreaJS", "condos/rent/{state}/{area}/scripts/
{filename}.js", "~/scripts/{filename}.js");
```

I found another question here on Stackoverflow: [Wildcards with ASP.NET MVC MapPageRoute to support organizing legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348360/wildcards-with-asp-net-mvc-mappageroute-to-support-organizing-legacy-code)

But I am not using MVC in this website. I have tried this:

```
routes.Add("CondosRentStateAreaJS", new Route("condos/rent/{state}/{area}/scripts/
{filename}.js", new StateAreaJSRouteHandler()));
```

And:

```
public class StateAreaJSRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            string filename = requestContext.RouteData.Values["filename"] as string;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/javascript";

                // find physical path to image here.  
                string filepath = requestContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/scripts/" + filename + ".js");

                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(filepath);
                requestContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Nut I don't think the code is called, because placing a break point in the line "string filename..." never hits.

Strangely enough, the CSS is there and the server inserts ../../../ before the folder/filename but the JS is missing.

So how do I correctly get /state/area/scripts/file.js to be just `"~/scripts/file.js"`?

--------------- EDIT ---------------

You definitely got me on the right track. I should add the scripts and stylesheets through the code-behind. I ended up getting a great solution like this:

```
HtmlGenericControl validatejs = new HtmlGenericControl("script");
validatejs.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");
    validatejs.Attributes.Add("src", ResolveUrl("~/scripts/validate.js"));
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(validatejs);


    HtmlLink fontscss = new HtmlLink();
    fontscss.Href = "~/styles/fonts.css";
    fontscss.Attributes.Add("rel", "stylesheet");
    fontscss.Attributes.Add("type", "text/css");
    this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(fontscss);
```

AND I just want to add (for other googlers) that this approach has enabled me to remove my JS and CSS CustomRouteHandlers, making the whole project more organized and probably faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just put the script reference in your master page? That way it will available and make it a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can also put the reference on the page it's being used on, or use the code below on your masterpage as suggested by Ashok. On the front side, use a literal and on the code behind do this (obviously change to your names):

```
litJquery.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"" + Page.ResolveClientUrl("~/js/jquery-1.6.min.js") + "\"></script>";
```

Good Luck!