# New project but including legacy site files

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used MVC to create several sites from scratch, but now I am tasked with a migration project.

Currently the site has a large static file base (*.html). Eventually every page will be migrated to MVC with views and controllers. The site lends itself to conversion very well with few nested folders and each folder with several pages. This should be a fairly straight forward job. But business dictates this must be done incrementally folder by folder, this is OK as each folder is fairly self contained and very few links go to other folders.

My question is can I just import the entire existing site into a folder named `legacy_html` in my VS project then configure routing to essentially ignore this folder, preserving the current site navigation for users.

As I migrate each folder, the folder would be deleted from legacy_html and controller and views be created.

The reason I ask is there are many root level folders and given eventually they will be all be migrated to controllers and views, I don't want them cluttering the project and getting in my way. My goal is to end up with a nice clean MVC folder structure at the end with no baggage.

Similar to [Wildcards with ASP.NET MVC MapPageRoute to support organizing legacy code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348360/wildcards-with-asp-net-mvc-mappageroute-to-support-organizing-legacy-code) but given the rate of development on MVC recently I would like to know if the answer has improved.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually want to have your "legacy" application urls handled by the RouteHandler, the simplest way to do this is to just add an ignore route into the `RegisterRoutes` method of your Global.asax:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{*html}", new {html=@".*\.html(/.*)?"});
```

This will cause requests for HTML pages to "fall through" the route handling and go look for the physical file, which is what they would traditionally do anyway.

[Source: Haacked](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx)